# Modify User.AboutMe inside community

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, chatter

I have the following code,

```
<apex:page standardController="User" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" >    
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:inputtextarea value="{!User.AboutMe}" required="true" styleClass="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}" styleclass="btn-success btn-margin" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true" styleClass="btn btn-margin" html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The problem is that I am not able to modify the text inside of the input box. It does display the about.Me of the correct user and will update if I modify from the default OOTB chatter page but it does not let me edit/modify the text.

How can I modify the text for this field? I am ok with it being an apex class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that a Community User doesn't have access to the User Object. See [Community User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) to see what default permissions they have.

Comment: How are they able to modify it from the OOTB page then? If they are able to modify it using the Salesforce default, in theory, they should be able to modify it this way right?

Comment: I suspect what you want to be allowing them to edit is their contact record and not their User record. Check to see where the about.me is actually stored. I'm not certain off-hand where that is without checking, but I don't think its in the User Object.

Comment: Currently I have the other parts of the page (name, email, phone, fax, etc) using the user record and they are able to make the needed modifications without any issues. I was using this, https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm as a guide to what is available for me to make modifications against.

Comment: Perhaps this doc will provide you with some additional insight: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf